# How to configure Serilog filters in xConnect?

Tags: xconnect, logging

I would like to filter out some messages from being logged in xConnect - for example 'Failed to locate activity...'.

I have tried this configuration but it does not seem to take effect:

```
<Settings>
  <Serilog>
    <Using>
      <FileSinkAssembly>Serilog.Sinks.File</FileSinkAssembly>
      <RollingFileSinkAssembly>Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile</RollingFileSinkAssembly>
    </Using>
    <MinimumLevel>
      <Default>Error</Default>
    </MinimumLevel>
    <WriteTo>
      <FileSink>
        <Name>RollingFile</Name>
        <Args>
          <pathFormat>App_Data\\Logs\\xconnect-log-${MachineName}-${InstanceName}-{Date}.txt</pathFormat>
          <retainedFileCountLimit>7</retainedFileCountLimit>
          <buffered>False</buffered>
        </Args>
      </FileSink>
    </WriteTo>
    <Filter>
      <Args>
        <Name>ByExcluding</Name>
        <expression>StartsWith(@Message, 'Failed to locate activity')</expression>
      </Args>
    </Filter>
    <Properties>
      <Application>XConnect</Application>
    </Properties>
  </Serilog>
</Settings>
```

Answer (score 2):

I contacted Sitecore support and they gave me a zip file  - they noted that this is not an officially tested method and do not guarantee it will work without causing any issues.

Looking at the zip file it contains:

1. Example xml config on how to configure:

```
<Settings>
  <Serilog>
    <Using>
      <FileSinkAssembly>Serilog.Sinks.File</FileSinkAssembly>
      <RollingFileSinkAssembly>Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile</RollingFileSinkAssembly>
      <SerilogFiltersExpressionsAssembly>Serilog.Filters.Expressions</SerilogFiltersExpressionsAssembly>
    </Using>
    <MinimumLevel>
      <Default>Information</Default>
    </MinimumLevel>
    <WriteTo>
      <FileSink>
        <Name>RollingFile</Name>
        <Args>
          <pathFormat>App_Data\\Logs\\xconnect-log-${MachineName}-${InstanceName}-{Date}.txt</pathFormat>
          <retainedFileCountLimit>7</retainedFileCountLimit>
          <buffered>False</buffered>
        </Args>
      </FileSink>
    </WriteTo>
    <Filter>
        <Filter1>
            <Name>ByExcluding</Name>
            <Args>
                <expression>(@Message like '%Failed to locate activity%' or @MessageTemplate like '%Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.SetFacetOperation%') and (@MessageTemplate not like '%Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.PatchFacetOperation%') and (@Exception like '%KeyBehaviorCache%'or @Exception like '%InteractionsCache%' or @Exception like '%ExmKeyBehaviorCache%' or @Exception like '%EngagementMeasures%' or @Exception like '%ContactBehaviorProfile%' or @Message like '%KeyBehaviorCache%'or @Message like '%InteractionsCache%' or @Message like '%ExmKeyBehaviorCache%' or @Message like '%EngagementMeasures%' or @Message like '%ContactBehaviorProfile%')</expression>
            </Args>
        </Filter1>
    </Filter>
    <Properties>
      <Application>XConnect</Application>
    </Properties>
  </Serilog>
</Settings>
```

2. Looks like the `Serilog.Filters.Expressions.dll` dll from [here](https://github.com/serilog-archive/serilog-filters-expressions/releases) and its dependency `Superpower.dll`.

So you can try those dll's, or you might want to contact sitecore support for them to provide the dll's for you.